# How to implement Trie with reduced memory usage in C++?

Tags: c++, memory-management, trie, low-memory

I need to implement a trie structure, to store approximately 30k strings.
Right now, the trie structure looks like this

```cpp
struct TrieNode {
        bool isWord=false;
        struct TrieNode* children[256];
};
```

For every node, i allocate too much space due to the array of fixed size, so my program is crashing because of huge memory usage.
For this problem, i can't use maps, which was the only solution i've found so far. Does anybody have any other tips?

thanks.

Comment: Does your data use a restricted alphabet, like, say, just ASCII letters? You might not need a full 256 element array

Comment: `struct TrieNode* children[256];` in `c++` you don't need the `struct`

Comment: Use a [Ternary Search Tree](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ternary-search-tree/).

Comment: @kiner_shah -- Too bad the code is written (badly) in `C`.  That implementation leaks like a sieve.

Comment: A pity, but perhaps we can use the sieve for finding prime numbers.

Comment: @Shawn it uses UTF-8 encoded characters (still might not need 256 elements, but when i tried to make it smaller, i still got the same errors)

Comment: @kiner_shah will give a look into that, thanks!

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, he need not follow that code completely :-P, he can write his own better version in C++. I just wanted to tell him about that data structure! ;-)

Comment: That's just my 2 cents comment, but `so my program is crashing because of huge memory usage` -> any decent computer should handle storing 30k structures such as you show them *easily*, without crashing because of a memory error. I'd say you should be able to store millions of such nodes, so I think there is another memory issue in your code.

Comment: Did you check that your code runs well with a smaller input ? If not, learn this sentence: *early optimization is the root of all evil*. Every year spent coding will teach you new ways of understanding the wisdom behind this sentence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `std::unordered_map<char, TrieNode>` instead of `TrieNode *` array.

If you need children sorted, use `std::map<char, TrieNode>`.

If you're not allowed to use STL, implement a hashmap or balanced binary tree class yourself.

Comment: i'm really not allowed to use STL, but i will try to make my own class as you suggested. thanks!

Comment: @kolho_m I really don't understand these restrictions to not use STL.  It isn't as if the program is going to magically write itself because you used `unordered_map` -- you still have to figure out the logic in how to use the map for your purposes.   There is no `trie` data structure in STL -- that should have been enough to allow usage of the various STL components so as to come up with a trie.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie totally agree with you. i really can't understand why, but since it's for a college assignment, i don't have much of a choice :(

Comment: Then those college assignments should first start out with you creating your own building blocks such as hash tables, linked lists, etc..  Then use those building blocks to create other data structures.   You now having to scramble to create your own hash table is to me, unfair for this assignment.   The hash table should have been assigned to you in a previous homework.  You now risk creating a faulty hash table, thus a faulty trie.